# Windows 8.1 Search does not automatically select first search match

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, modern-ui, windows-search

When I search in Windows 8/8.1 (start menu->start typing), it doesn't automatically highlight the search term.  For example, if I'm trying to open the "Internet Options" panel and type the entire thing out in search, I have to down arrow or tab to the "Internet Options" search result.  This is retarded.  I'm used to Windows 7 style search where the first match is highlighted and i can easily just hit return.

First match highlighting does work for other built-in things like "Control Panel", but it should work for all things in general, as it did in Windows 7 search.

Anyways, if there is an option to enable this in Windows 8/8.1, I'd appreciate the tip.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct fix for your issue, but rather a workaround. I understand your issue, and I believe your main complaint is having to remove your hands from the keyboard to the mouse in order to click on the searched term. What I do as an alternative, as I have experienced the same issue with you on 8.1, is type the search term, then a quick down arrow followed by an enter key will select/initiate your first searched term.